# Using the DbConfiguration class with Entity Framework ObjectContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a C# application using Entity Framework and ObjectContext. I wish to implement connection resiliency like mentioned here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456835(v=vs.113).aspx

How do I assign the DbConfiguration class to the ObjectContext (i.e. how do I 'tell' the ObjectContext to use the configuration)?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj680699(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Thanks, but it says: "Place your DbConfiguration class in the same assembly as your DbContext class". I do not use DbContext but ObjectContext. Will this still work?

Comment: Nope, it does not work with ObjectContext. Tried in dummy application for DbContext and it works as advertised. Any other suggestions to make it work with ObjectContext?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a configuration class which is extended from `DbMigrationsConfiguration<YourContext>`

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<YourContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        ContextKey = "YourContext_";
    }

    protected override void Seed(YourContext context)
    {
        //Migrate your data
    }
}
```